# Keep track of time constantly without the use of threads

Tags: python, multithreading

How do I keep track of time constantly without the use of threads? I'm asking this as threads in python are generally looked down on especially because it "adds complexity" to any program. My program needs to receive/send WiFi commands, receive/send XBee(Serial) commands, as well as keeping track of time constantly.

What is the best solution to this? Should I go ahead and use threads or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "keep track of time constantly"? Couldn't you, for instance, place a call to `time.time` immediately before every point that needs to know the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of threading/multiprocessing, you can also use [timer signals](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer), which might be a little easier than "instrumenting the program" to do the calls itself, or otherwise creating your own main loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can either instrument the program so that it makes regular calls to a timekeeping function, or you can use threads.

If the timekeeping could be done by a second *process* that'd be better in terms of management complexity, but you don't say why you need the time, so I can't judge whether that's a possibility.

Threads are not evil, they just shouldn't be your first resort.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I need to keep track of time to display to the user the current time. But also do you have any idea on receiving/sending Wifi commands? I mean for any communication protocols dont you have to use threads?

Comment: @TabishChasmawala That depends on whether *asynchronous APIs* are available. If you use calls that don't immediately return, doing their work in the background, then **your** application doesn't necessarily need threads - the library uses them instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else you’re doing: if the other operations you’re performing just involve I/O through file descriptors, then you can use [one of the select calls](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/select.html). Specify a timeout, so that if nothing happens within that interval, the call returns so you can update your clock before making the call again.